# Erlang - pattern matching with tuples

Tags: erlang

If I write simply:

```
 [X || X <- [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]].
```

it returns:

```
 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

If I write:

```
[{a,b} || {a,b} <- [{1,2},{2,3}]].
```

it returns

```
[]
```

Simply question - why?

Comment: While the answer below is correct, I would like to mention that you probably meant to do `[{A,B} || {A,B} <- [{1,2},{2,3}]].`.

Comment: The notation comes from mathematics, and should be read declaratively. In the second case, if you read the generator as "for all pairs {A,B} in the list" it gets pretty clear why any non-matching elements are ignored. You could add furter conditions apart from the pattern; for instance, [... || {A,B} <- List, A > B] only selects pairs where A is larger than B.

Answer (score 3):

Generator **{a,b} <- [{1,2},{2,3}]** is a filter at the same time. So when the element does not match the pattern it's just skipped.

```
Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.2] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false] [dtrace]

Eshell V8.2  (abort with ^G)
1>  [X || X <- [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]].
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
2> [{a,b} || {a,b} <- [{1,2},{2,3}]].
[]
3> [{a,b} || {a,b} <- [{1,2},{2,3},{a,b}]].
[{a,b}]
4>
```

you can read more about list comprehensions from [learnyousomeerlang](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/starting-out-for-real#list-comprehensions)

```
7> Weather = [{toronto, rain}, {montreal, storms}, {london, fog},{paris, sun}, {boston, fog}, {vancouver, snow}].
[{toronto,rain},
 {montreal,storms},
 {london,fog},
 {paris,sun},
 {boston,fog},
 {vancouver,snow}]
8>  FoggyPlaces = [X || {X, fog} <- Weather].
[london,boston]
9>  FoggyPlaces = [X || {X, fog1} <- Weather].
** exception error: no match of right hand side value []
10>  [X || {X, fog1} <- Weather].
[]
11>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I write:

```
[{A,B} || {A,B} <- [{1,2},{2,3}]].
```

it returns

```
[{1,2},{2,3}]
```

Comment: it simply means that Uppercase means numbers while Lowercase means atom 'values'? thanks a lot

Comment: @Kornelia: Almost, Uppercase means variables, Lowercase means atoms as well as `'Atom with Uppercase'`.